# Failed to load plugin class [org.elasticsearch.xpack.XPackPlugin]]; nested: InvocationTargetException; nested: NoSuchFieldError[V_5_6_0]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

We are getting below exception while working with elastic search x-pack while loading . stack trace is as below while creating PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.

ElasticsearchException[Failed to load plugin class [org.elasticsearch.xpack.XPackPlugin]]; nested: InvocationTargetException; nested: NoSuchFieldError[V_5_6_0];
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:430)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.(PluginsService.java:102)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.newPluginService(TransportClient.java:101)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:126)

```
Using below dependencies.

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-lasticsearch</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
     <artifactId>x-pack-transport</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
       <version>5.4.3</version> 
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
        <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.58</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.58</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it seems that you have a lot of different version of `elasticsearch` artifacts (6.2, 5.6 and 5.4). My guess would be that one artifact is expecting a 5.6 version of another one.

Comment: Tried it out, but this is breaking other classes of application.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue while starting my spring boot application. I had missed to include bouncycastle dependency in my maven pom.xml. After adding this, my application started perfectly.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.60</version>
</dependency>
```